Kernel Restarting: The kernel for .ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically
I have trained a model using keras.
Model summary:
Model: "sequential_1"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                    ┃ Output Shape           ┃       Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ lstm_1 (LSTM)                   │ (None, 200, 6)         │           312 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ flatten_1 (Flatten)             │ (None, 1200)           │             0 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_2 (Dense)                 │ (None, 128)            │       153,728 │
├─────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────────┤
│ dense_3 (Dense)                 │ (None, 2)              │           258 │
└─────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────┘
 Total params: 462,896 (1.77 MB)
 Trainable params: 154,298 (602.73 KB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Optimizer params: 308,598 (1.18 MB)

I have tried to convert my model for Android usig tflite conveter. I used following code:
import tensorflow as tf 

import os 
os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'

# Convert the model.
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
  tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, # enable TensorFlow Lite ops.
  tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS # enable TensorFlow ops.
]
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('My_Model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)

When I run this conversion, it restarting my kernel and printing following error in jupyter notebook terminal:
[I 2024-05-15 11:34:06.899 ServerApp] Saving file at /ml_codes/poc/MyModel.ipynb
[I 2024-05-15 11:34:35.986 ServerApp] AsyncIOLoopKernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
[W 2024-05-15 11:34:35.986 ServerApp] kernel 171cb42f-92a2-405c-a1c9-6489095f343e restarted
[I 2024-05-15 11:34:36.002 ServerApp] Starting buffering for 171cb42f-92a2-405c-a1c9-6489095f343e:b45e968e-d91c-4761-bd02-5bf4a93dc15f
[I 2024-05-15 11:34:36.021 ServerApp] Connecting to kernel 171cb42f-92a2-405c-a1c9-6489095f343e.
[I 2024-05-15 11:34:36.021 ServerApp] Restoring connection for 171cb42f-92a2-405c-a1c9-6489095f343e:b45e968e-d91c-4761-bd02-5bf4a93dc15f
[I 2024-05-15 11:35:07.565 ServerApp] Saving file at /ml_codes/poc/MyModel.ipynb
2024-05-15 11:35:12.957443: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:210] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX512F FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-05-15 11:35:13.726656: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-05-15 11:35:15.100616: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2251] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...

My python version: 3.10.12
Tensorflow versoin: 2.16.1
Is there any solution to that problem?

There's no error in the message, only warnings (and you can ignore them in that case). Have you checked that you get the My_Model.tflite file?

@Lescurel No, the kernel crashed and no Model generated
